# Cisco 7960 SIP phone background image issues

Tags: cisco, voip, sip, cisco-voip, tftp

I have an asterisk home PBX and I recently got a Cisco 7960G on eBay. So far I got everything working but the background images are quite tricky. I followed one short how-to and I was able to actually upload an image onto the phone. But when I tried making my own image, it just fails weirdly. Left to right, the image starts to display in about 1/3 of the original image and it is then wrapped around so the first 1/3 of the image is on the far right. I checked that my image is 90x56 greyscale bmp just as the example given on that website. The example image works fine. Can someone please tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

I am serving the image from nginx over http (not https), the line in `SIPDefault.cnf` is:

(breaking the link up with spaces so that stackexchange doesn't think this is a link. I don't have enough rep to post that many links, apparently.

> logo_url: "http:// my_server_hostname/ sip/ homer.bmp"

This does not work at all:
[image: My picture of Homer Simpson that does not work at all]

How it looks on my phone:
[image: How my Homer picture looks on my phone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it was all down to bmp encoding. When exporting (in GIMP) with these settings, it does work all okay. Sorry for wasting your time :-)

[image: GIMP BMP settings compatible with Cisco 7960 phone]

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: yeah, I know ... but it wanted me to wait 2 days and I totally forgot. Thanks for reminding me :-)